# Vertical Carousel jQuery

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to create a Carousel, my first attempt at first ever. http://jsfiddle.net/PmNM5/

HTML holds UL LI, each LI has 2 images both accumulate width of 242px and height = 81px

Out of several LI, only 3 should be visible (i.e. 6 images will be visble, as One LI holds 2 images, float:left each.)

UL : is set to display BLOCK, with WIDTH of 242px. HTML is displaying perfectly. but carousel doesnt work, as I know I need to calculate TOP smartly which Im lacking.

```
<div id="home_carousel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#img1" class="inline cboxElement"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/home-truck1.jpg"></a>
            </li>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myCarousel = {

    setHeight: function() {

        var $img = $('li', '#home_carousel');
        var total = 81 * $img.length;

        $('#home_carousel ul').height(total);

    },

    slide: function() {
        var outPart = $('#home_carousel ul').outerHeight();
        $('#home_carousel_up').on('click', function() {

            var $a = $(this);

            $('#home_carousel ul').animate({
                top: -81 + outPart + 'px'
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');

        });

        $('#home_carousel_down').on('click', function() {

            var $a = $(this);

            $('#home_carousel ul').animate({
                top: 81 + 'px'
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');

        });

    },

    init: function() {
        this.setHeight();
        this.slide();
    }

};

myCarousel.init();
```

Comment: `easeOutBounce` isn't defined in the base JQuery library. Are you also including the JQuery UI Effects library?

Comment: I tried this it works, but my problem is carousel doesnt work after 2nd click. Since im using static value of TOP to animate. I need a help on how to get dynamic TOP of UL everytime !

Comment: something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/PmNM5/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PmNM5/7/)

I have written all logic for top offset and stopping animation at ends points.

When scrolling top the condition would be:

```
($('#home_carousel ul').position().top - 81) >  (242 - outPart)
```

And when scrolling down condition would be:

```
$('#home_carousel ul').position().top + 81 <= 0
```

I have harcoded all values. Please store numbers like 81 and 242 (wrapper height) in variables. It would be great if you calculate heights via jquery .outerHeight method. In that case if height gets changed due to change in your markup or CSS then your code will not break.

Comment: Thanks, i was stuck at logic. it works. Now im trying if its last, then clicking TOP should rewind.